# Deleting the contents of the file not working

Tags: c++, file-io, delete-file

I'm writing, reading and deleting the content of a file. Eeverything works fine except the delete part, as when I press `y` it says deleted but doesn't display any records.

```
typedef struct ch
{
    char str[10];
};

void disp(ch d)
{
    cout<<"\n"<<d.str<<"\n";
}
//delete part
cout<<"\nwant to delete??";
char c;
cin>>c;
if(c=='y')
{
    char s[10];
    cout<<"nter - ";
    cin>>s;
    file.seekg(0);
    int found=0;
    fstream temp("temp.dat",ios::in|ios::out|ios::app);
    while(file.read((char *)&dta,sizeof(dta)))
    {
        if(strcmp(dta.str,s)==0)
        {
            found=1;
            cout<<"deleted";
        }
        else
        temp.write((char *)&dta,sizeof(dta));
    }
    if(!found)
        cout<<"not found";
    remove("new.dat");
    rename("temp.dat","new.dat");
    temp.close();
    file.open("new.dat",ios::in|ios::out|ios::app);
}
```

Comment: You might want to run your program in a debugger, and step though it line by line. You also should provide the declaration of `dta`. And finally, when deleting entries from a file, you should read from the *original* file and write to the temporary file.

Comment: The delete part is working as expected, the new.dat file will contain all the records but the deleted.

Comment: your `typedef` is wrong should be `typedef struct { char str[16]; } ch;`, enable all the warning with `-Wall`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Looking over your code again, I see the problem is that you are using the ios::app although you have also passed ios::in.

> ios::app -- All output operations are performed at the end of the file, appending
>   the content to the current content of the file. This flag can only be
>   used in streams open for output-only operations.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

**Old Post:**

Take a look at the following code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

const char g_szTestData[] = "This is some test da$$$$######ta and some more"
                            " tes$$$$######ting";

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    fstream file("new.dat", ios::in|ios::out);
    file << g_szTestData << flush;

    cout << "Do you want to delete all $$$$######?";
    if (cin.get() == 'y')
    {
        char szBuffer[10];                  //< File read buffer
        char szString[11] = "$$$$######";   //< 10 characters + '\0'
        bool bFound = false;

        fstream temp("temp.dat", ios::out);
        file.seekg(0, file.beg);

        while (file.read(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer)))
        {
            if (strncmp(szBuffer,szString,10) == 0) bFound = true;
            else temp.write(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer));
        }

        temp.flush();
        temp.close();

        if (bFound)
        {
            file.close();
            remove("new.dat");
            rename("temp.dat", "new.dat");
            file.open("new.dat",ios::in|ios::out);
        }
        else cout << "Pattern Not Found!" << endl;
    }

    /* Do something with the contents of file. */

    // Lets clean up at the end
    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

In this example, a file is created and the contents `g_szTestData` are added, you can verify this by opening the file (before pressing 'y').

The user is then asked if they would like to delete a string of 10 characters `$$$$######` from the file.  If the user wishes to proceed, a new file is opened `temp.dat`. The program gradually walks through the existing `new.dat` file (10 characters at a time).  If the string the program reads from `new.dat` is not the target string, the string is written to the temp file.

If the target string is found, both files are closed, the old file is deleted and the new file is renamed to the name of the old file.  The new file is then opened so the program can do additional work on its contents.

Instead of having a fixed 10 character string, it is possible to ask the user for the string they wish to remove using `cin >> szString` but the string would need to be 10 characters long.

Answer (score 1):

Your code work as expected, it only display `deleted` because `disp()` isn't called anywhere.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>

#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    char str[16];
} ch;

static void disp(ch d) {
    cout<<d.str<<"\n";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    fstream file;
    ch dta;

    file.open("new.dat",ios::in|ios::out|ios::trunc);
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        snprintf((char *)&dta.str, sizeof(dta.str)-1, "rec%d", i);
        file.write((char *)&dta,sizeof(dta));
    }

    //delete part
    {
        char s[16] = "rec1";
        file.seekg(0);
        int found=0;
        fstream temp("temp.dat",ios::out);
        while(file.read((char *)&dta,sizeof(dta))) {
            if(strcmp(dta.str, s)==0) {
                found=1;
                cout<<"deleted * ";
                disp(dta);
            } else {
                temp.write((char *)&dta,sizeof(dta));
                disp(dta);
            }
        }
        if(!found)
            cout<<"not found";
        file.close();
        remove("new.dat");
        rename("temp.dat","new.dat");
        temp.close();
    }
}
```